# How to select Option in php from my array?

Tags: php

I'm trying to select the values from the given array.If same value returns in array I need option to be selected.how to do that ?

**Html**

```
<select multiple="" class="Designers" style="width: 100px;">            
                          <option value="JOhn">JOhn</option>
                          <option value="JOhn1">JOhn1</option>
                          <option value="JOhn2">JOhn2</option>
                        </select>
```

**PHP**

```
 Array ( [0] => JOhn[1] => JOhn2);
$DesignerGet =  Array ( [0] => JOhn[1] => JOhn2[2] => JOhn2);
$DesinerEdit = explode(',',$DesignerGet);

<?php if('JOhn2' ==  'JOhn2'){ ?>
 <option value="JOhn1">JOhn1</option>
<?php } ?>
```

**Expected Result**

```
<select multiple="" class="Designers" style="width: 100px;">            
                          <option value="JOhn" selected>JOhn</option>
                          <option value="JOhn1">JOhn1</option>
                          <option value="JOhn2" selected>JOhn2</option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: what is $DesignerGet array.?

Comment: $DesignerGet =  Array ( [0] => JOhn[1] => JOhn2[2] => JOhn2);

Comment: first put your complete code. second your effort. third your expected outcome. then only anyone can help. and both codes are not complete.

Comment: tell me based on your `$DesignerGet` array you are goin to make the drop down or not?

Comment: yes im making drop down using that one

Comment: yes i tried i don't put down vote for u

Comment: Does it work for you? @QuestionUser. If yes then you can upvote or accept it as an answer.

Comment: Try all answer. if you got solution with more than one. choose the most appropriate one and marked as an answer. to others you can upvote thanks. but atlesat mark as an answer if you get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_unique() function before use an array.

```
$DesinerEdit = array_unique($DesignerGet);
```

It removes duplicate values and you can use the array as you want.

[Refer php manual for this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: Do you want to compare two arrays?

Comment: check the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $DesignerGet =  Array ( [0] => JOhn[1] => JOhn2[2] => JOhn2);
    foreach($DesinerEdit as $key=>$val)
    {
       $selected = ($val == 'JOhn1')?"selected ='selected' ":'';
       <option value="JOhn1" <?php echo $selected ?>>JOhn1</option> 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
<?php
    $arra = Array ('JOhn','JOhn2'); 
    $option = Array ('JOhn','JOhn1','JOhn2');
?>

<select multiple class="Designers" style="width: 100px;">            
    <?php foreach($option as $key => $value){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value;?>" <?php echo (in_array($value,$arra)) ? 'selected' : '';?>><?php echo $value;?></option>
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Here I have used [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function for checking the values if values is within the get array then it'll be selected else not